# EasyPHP unexpected end of apache

Tags: apache2, easyphp

I am using EasyPHP 5.4.6 on a Vista laptop. It worked fine, but since I restarted, there was a window update, apache doesn't work and says: "Unexpected end of Apache!"

I know usually this means that an other service uses port 80. So I used `netstat -a` to see which process use my port 80 but none uses it. Alternativelly I tried to run my apache on port 8887 and 8181, neither one of them would make my apache to run.

Would anyone have an idea on how to troubleshoot this?

GB

Comment: check the apache error log. it's unlikely to be a port ownership fight.

Comment: No errors in apache errors logs recorded related to this. Only old errors there...

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine suggested to run the apache.exe in command line so I did and it saved me. DOS ouput some critical information to help me. So in my case I had a bad config in httpd.conf, but EasyPhp was silent about it...